# React Native - W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've tried to run my React Native on android and everything looks good while getting data from rest API,

but I dont know why when I want to send data into rest API the console log tell me

> `W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry`

here's the code I've tried :

```
try {
  console.log(Constants.APILink + `DoAudit/PostCompleteAuditSchedulev1`, header + `token`)
  axios.post(Constants.APILink + `DoAudit/PostCompleteAuditSchedulev1`, header, {
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + Queries.getPersistentData('token')
    }
  })
// NEVER RUN TO THIS STATEMENT OR SHOWING ME AN ERROR IN LOGCAT
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data == 0) {
        console.log("Upload success HEADER");

        var path = '/storage/emulated/0/Documents' + '/testx.txt';
        RNFS.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(mediaListFinding + auditid), 'ascii')
          .then((success) => {
            console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
            let dataAdd = NativeModules.SqliteModule;
            dataAdd.insert(mediaListFinding, 0, auditid, function (value){
              console.log("Service callback insert " + value);
            })
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
            });
        this.setState({
          loaderStatus: false
        })
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      this.setState({
        loaderStatus: false
      })
    });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
  this.setState({
    loaderStatus: false
  })
}
```

I've tried to catch every error and using console to tell me what happen, but the logcat just showing me this:

[image: logcat]

next log never seeking

> `Upload Success HEADER` or Error catch

Comment: there's still no idea how to fix it?

Comment: i'm having the same problem. i get a blank screen, nothing happens, eventually the app breaks and when I open logcat I get this line after some Java errors

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. My app doesn't load and just shows a blank screen. Any touches will log `W/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached`. Still searching

Comment: Hi there, any fix?